# Не работает get_redirect_url в RedirectView из документации

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

В [документации](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/class-based-views/base/#redirectview) указан следующий пример:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.views.generic.base import RedirectView

from articles.models import Article

class ArticleCounterRedirectView(RedirectView):

    permanent = False
    query_string = True
    pattern_name = 'article-detail'

    def get_redirect_url(self, *args, **kwargs):
        article = get_object_or_404(Article, pk=kwargs['pk'])
        article.update_counter()
        return super(ArticleCounterRedirectView, self).get_redirect_url(*args, **kwargs)
```

Я делаю полностью по аналогии:

```
class UserAddToFriendView(LoginRequiredMixin, RedirectView):
    pattern_name = 'users:detail'
    permanent = False
    query_string = True
    model = User

    def get_success_url(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print(kwargs['username'])
        user = get_object_or_404(User, username=kwargs['username'])
        Friend.objects.add_friend(self.request.user, user)
        return super(UserAddToFriendView, self).get_redirect_url(*args, **kwargs)
```

Но не работает, и `print()` не отрабатывает.

Но добавив метод `post()`

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    user = get_object_or_404(User, username=kwargs['username'])
    Friend.objects.add_friend(self.request.user, user)
    return super(UserAddToFriendView, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Всё работает.

Что не так?